# Own Coordinates for JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                addListener(panel);
                panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1));
                grid.add(panel);
```

-

```
public void addListener(JPanel p) {
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(panelX);
                System.out.println(panelY);
            }
        });
```

How can I set a `X-coordinate` and a `Y-coordinate` for each panel? `(If i = 5 and j = 2, panelX should be 2 and panelY should be 5)`. If the panel is clicked it has to return the `X` and `Y` of the panel.

Comment: What is the above for loop implies.and For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: You mean, you want to get coordinates of cursor when you click on JPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            addListener(panel, j, i);
            panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black,1));
            grid.add(panel);
```

-

```
public void addListener(JPanel p, final int x, final int y) {
    p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: or better by using put/getClientProperty